# Update values from database

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a table called `employees` with the columns:

- id
- departament_id
- salary

and I want to raise the salary by `10%` for the employees working in the same department as the employee with `id=115`, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data first (based on Scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> create table test as select deptno, empno id, ename, sal from emp;

Table created.

SQL> select * From test where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO         ID ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7782 CLARK            2450
        10       7839 KING            10000
        10       7934 MILLER           1300

SQL>
```

Let's change salaries for all employees of department 10 - I'll pass Clark's ID as a parameter:

```
SQL> merge into test t
  2    using (select a.deptno
  3           from test a
  4           where a.id = &par_id
  5          ) x
  6    on (x.deptno = t.deptno)
  7    when matched then update set
  8      t.sal = t.sal * 1.1;
Enter value for par_id: 7782

3 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO         ID ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7782 CLARK            2695
        10       7839 KING            11000
        10       7934 MILLER           1430

SQL>
```

Now that you know *how*, apply it to your table.